# f:convertDateTime displays wrong hour

Tags: jsf, datetime, primefaces

I have datetime in my DB. When I try to display it, the "hour" is wrong (6 hours more).

```
DB          2013-03-12 10:05:49
Display     2013/03/12 16:05:49
```

I'm using primefaces and this is the code:

```
<p:column id="fecha" headerText="Fecha" style="text-align: center">
  <h:outputText value="#{con.fecha}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"  />
  </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

I tried to use the pattern `HH`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

in your `web.xml` try pasting these lines:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are facing TimeZone issues...

I solved this problem getting my timeZone from [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html#timeZone) and changing the f:convertDateTime  like this:

From

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"  />
```

To

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="America/Montevideo" />
```

This is not fancy but it works.

A better solution you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110127/2359447) by adding this code into de web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```